# enabling versioning for s3 bucket object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I want to enable versioning for my s3 bucket object aka nested files inside my bucket.

```
object = s3.Bucket('ben-uguru').Object('db.sqlite')
object.configure_versioning(versioning=True)
print object
```

In this case I'd want the file 'db.sqlite' inside the bucket 'ben-uguru' have versioning enabled. However the problem that I get is `AttributeError: 's3.Object' object has no attribute 'configure_versioning'`

Answer (score 5):

With boto3, check and change versioning state.

```
import boto3


bucket_name = 'avilpage'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
versioning = s3.BucketVersioning(bucket_name)

# check status
print(versioning.status)

# enable versioning
versioning.enable()

# disable versioning
versioning.suspend()
```

S3 Docs: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketversioning

Comment: Question is about "object versioning". This answer talks about "bucket versioning"

Answer (score 3):

Figured the issue and found a way to do it on boto3

```
bucket_versioning = s3.BucketVersioning('ben-uguru')
bucket_versioning.enable()
```

Refer back to http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucketversioning

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable the versioning on the `s3.Bucket` instance and not on the `Object` instance, you can use:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('ben-uguru')
bucket.configure_versioning(True)
```

For futher information look: [S3 - boto.configure_versioning](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.configure_versioning)

Comment: Doesn't work AttributeError: 's3.Bucket' object has no attribute 'configure_versioning' still throws me the same error

Comment: I'm using boto3...?

Comment: sorry I assumed it was boto my apologies.